# ProgressDialog is now deprecated

Tags: android, progressdialog

The Progress Dialog is deprecated now for android O. 
What is the solution for this?

I am getting below warnings . In My project

```
Warning:(6, 20) 'Progress Dialog' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
Warning:(72, 43) 'Progress Dialog' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
Warning:(89, 27) 'Progress Dialog' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
```

I didn't find solution for the same problem.

Comment: Thanks @DimaRostopira. I already check above link. That you mentioned

Answer (score 2):

According to google:

> This class was deprecated in API level 26. ProgressDialog is a modal
>   dialog, which prevents the user from interacting with the app. Instead
>   of using this class, you should use a progress indicator like
>   ProgressBar, which can be embedded in your app's UI. Alternatively,
>   you can use a notification to inform the user of the task's progress.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Answer (score 2):

Custom ProgressBar is the answer. You can write your own or use something like DelayedProgressDialog from https://github.com/Q115/DelayedProgressDialog

Usage:

```
DelayedProgressDialog progressDialog = new DelayedProgressDialog();
progressDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
```