# Alternative to ProgressDialog for loading data?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have an App with retrofit and I make some calls to an `Api` (like a LogIn in this case), some of them take a few seconds to load, so I want to know when I should make a loading screen and lock the interaction with the user. I see that `ProgressDialog` is deprecated now, and they don't display it but they lock the interaction with the view. What should be better?

Comment: Can you query only a percentage of the data first, then load more as the users requires it?

Comment: Check "inderteminate progress bar".  Show it on call and hide it when api call success. Use match parent for width and height. Use frame laout as the viewgroup

Comment: They are deprecated, but unlikely to go away any time soon. They are usable, but just to be on the safe side, do what @nfl-x said.

Comment: @nfl-x but an "indeterminate progress bar" dont block the ui interaction, and in a Login should be better to locked to prevent the user interaction with the ui meanwhile the request being done.

Comment: `ProgressBar` is not deprecated, you are wrong

Comment: Thanks @David. Glad it helped you!!

Comment: Thanks to you @SumitShukla !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First of all it is not `ProgressBar` but it is `ProgressDialog` because it locks down user interaction until it hides.
- You can use a progress indicator like `ProgressBar`, which can be embedded in your app's UI. Alternatively, you can use a `notification` to inform the user of the task's progress.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45860005/7254873)
- A `skeleton screen` helps load a user interface gradually, a little at a time. This means that the barebones UI displays first. Then the loaded content is gradually populated on-screen.
- `Shimmer effect` was created by `Facebook` to indicate a loading status, so instead of using `ProgressBar` or usual loader use `Shimmer` for a better design and user interface.

Comment: If i want to lock the user interaction in a login to prevent that the user click again login button (or any other button in the view) what should i do?

Comment: Then? The grace isn't in not blocking the interaction with the user?

Comment: You can disable or hide login button once it is clicked until response as success or not is received  something like that. And there are many more things you can do!!